# HttpConnection cannot be cast to Connection$Response while taking response code in Jsoup

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I am using `Jsoup API 1.8.3` to parse all links present in a website generated using PHP. Home page, contact forms like pages are getting parsed successfully. But for login page it fails due to:

> HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404,
>   https://.../info/en/loginMf.php?src=trading

It is failing because it requires valid credentials. Hence I want to skip such URLs.
I am trying to get it done by checking the status code using:

```
Connection.Response response=(Response) Jsoup.connect(path);//Added typecast
  System.out.println(response.statusCode());
```

But this added type cast gives error on runtime as: `classCastException`.

What is the exact way to get the status code for URL hit, before it is passed to `parse()` method?

**Edit:**

I tried to adopt the answer given by @lonesome[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287393/5146424), as follows:

```
        try
          {
            Connection.Response response= Jsoup.connect(path).execute();
            int statusCode=response.statusCode();
            if (statusCode <= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
                 doc = Jsoup.connect(filename).get();//web crawling
                  }

          } 
                 catch(HttpStatusException http)
                 {
                     System.out.println("Status:"+http.getStatusCode());
                     http.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

But problem is, `int statusCode=response.statusCode();` line is not getting executed. This is may be because the way `jsoup` works. It need to execute to send back the response as answered by @lucksch.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect-java.lang.String-), `Jsoup.connect` returns a `Connection`, not a `Connection.Response`. So why are you trying to cast a connection to a response?

Comment: @RealSkeptic:Yes that was my misunderstanding. It got cleared from one of answer below.

Comment: I guess you are catching a wrong exception. In addition, like what I said previously, first do not use `jsoup`. crear a HTTPconnection and etc like my answer. Then, within the second `if` body, use the `jsoup` so it will be surely working, I hope you understand my explaination here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
                  HttpURLConnection httpConn;
                  URL url = new URL("adr");

                  URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                  int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

                   if (connection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                      try{
                          httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

                     if (statusCode <= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
                             // means the connection was successful
                             //do crawling
                       }
             }
     } 
                   catch (ConnectException ex) { java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(crawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}  //catch the possible exception.
                   catch (SSLHandshakeException |SocketException | SocketTimeoutException | UnknownHostException ex) {java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(crawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   //replace crawler with the name of your program main class
```

Comment: Can you help to understand, what is _url_ in `url.connection()`. Is it an instance of URL class of Java? where should I pass the path of link?

Comment: This seems not `Jsoup API`. Please correct me if I am wrong as am also using it for first time.

Comment: url is an instance of `URL` class. And yes, it is not Jsoup but so what? you still need to get the statuscode and compare it like in here. same thing.

Comment: +1 for the logic as I do get it. My problem is `Jsoup` is not allowing me to take even the status code. So with this approach it will not even go to `if` condition.

Comment: See what I mean now? Check the status code and if it was within that boundary, then go for crawling, if not, then do not go further. Meanwhile, you can take care of any exception using `try-cacth`. You can even leave the catch body `{}` empty.

Comment: @mk08 At least, you can us this way to check the `statuscode`, if it was successful, then use `jasoup` within the second `if` body. That is the worst case scenario if you couldn't adopt this answer with `jsoup`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97973/discussion-between-mk08-and-lonesome).

Comment: Well I managed to get it done as per this answer. Only modification I did is to instantiate `httpConn` object as ` HttpURLConnection httpConn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`
    `statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();`

Comment: Great then. That difference is probably due to the `Jsoup` API.

Answer (score 1):

You get a Response only when you actually fire a request against the website you want. So this is how you would get it:

```
Connection.Response response= Jsoup.connect(path).execute();
```

The `execute` method returns a `Connection.Response`, which contains the status codes.

Comment: Thanks for `execute()` method. At least I am now not getting `TypeCastException`. Now I am trying to get that code like `System.out.println(response.statusCode());` but it is throwing HTTP exception, immediately on `execute()` line. Hence not able to assert the status. :(

Comment: @mk08 the error `404` is the status code. Just check it like what I showed in my answer. the `if` condition I mean.

Comment: I am glad I could help. The HTTP exception is a new problem quite different. Without the url you try to access it will be hard to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

JSoup throws an HttpStatusException when a not OK HTTP response is returned. Here is a demonstration program that will show you how to properly validate urls using JSoup. I build up a list of urls, of course you are already getting that list from somewhere.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.HttpStatusException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class JSoupMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> allUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        allUrls.add("http://en.wikipedia.org");
        allUrls.add("http://en.wikipedia.org/blah"); //<---This will cause a 404 status code to be returned
        allUrls.add("http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3");

        System.out.println("Checking urls");
        List<String> goodUrls = getGoodUrls(allUrls);

        System.out.println("\r\nGood urls");
        for(String url : goodUrls)
        {
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getGoodUrls(List<String> allUrls)
    {
        List<String> goodUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String url : allUrls)
        {
            try
            {
                Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                goodUrls.add(url);
            }
            catch(HttpStatusException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Url " + url + " resulted in " + e.getStatusCode());
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return goodUrls;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed returning me an error code 404 in my case. However, it is getting captured in Exception. I would like to get this status code even before exception so that I can avoid parsing that particular URL. I wonder if it is possible or not. If not then I'll find workaround with this approach.